# "Yes"/"No" string based on 1/0 integer condition

Tags: powerbi, dax

Power Bi is getting data from MySQL from the table `Vehicle Supports`. In the website there is an enum of `1 = Yes` and `0 = No`.

I have a Donut chart which is displaying the integers since the data being saved in DB are integers.

[image]

I can't use conditional formatting as some tutorials mention since this is not a table. I also tried `FORMAT()` and didn't work.

How can I format the integers? If the number is 1 then change it to "Yes" and if the number is 0 then change it to No.

Comment: Why don't you just change this in your SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/if-function-dax

```
String = IF(number=1,"Yes","No")
```